# How to plot top 5 values in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How can I plot the top 5 values that appear to be the biggest in this plot? (`Wii`,`NES`,`GB`,`DS`,`X360`)

```
sns.violinplot(x=df['Global_Sales'],y=df['Platform'],data=df)
```

[image]

Comment: `sns.violinplot(x='Global_Sales',y='Platform',data=df.sort_values('Global_Sales').tail(5))`

Comment: Filter the dataframe using `sort_values` then `head(5)` and plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure `x` and `y` are column *names*<sup>‡</sup> and then sort/filter the `data` argument:

- Either use [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) (fastest):

  ```
  sns.violinplot(
      x='Global_Sales',
      y='Platform',
      data=df.nlargest(5, 'Global_Sales')
  )
  ```
- Or [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html):

  ```
      ...
      data=df.sort_values('Global_Sales').tail(5)
  ```
- Or `sort_values(ascending=False)` with [`head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

  ```
      ...
      data=df.sort_values('Global_Sales', ascending=False).head(5)
  ```

---

<sup>‡</sup> In OP's code, `x` and `y` are column **data** (`x=df['Global_Sales']`) instead of column **names** (`x='Global_Sales'`). If `x` and `y` are actual data, the `data` param is ignored, so `df` would need to be sorted/filtered before the plotting command.